# Identify the day diff between 2 dates in a column and flag the pattern in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame([["A","2023-02-04"],["A","2023-02-05"],["A","2023-02-06"],["B","2023-02-06"],["B","2023-02-13"],["B","2023-02-20"],
                      ["C","2023-02-07"],["C","2023-02-10"],["C","2023-02-12"],["D","2023-02-14"],["D","2023-02-17"],["D","2023-02-20"],
                      ["E","2023-02-18"]],columns=["id","date"])
```

```
id     date
A   2023-02-04
A   2023-02-05
A   2023-02-06
B   2023-02-06
B   2023-02-13
B   2023-02-20
C   2023-02-07
C   2023-02-10
C   2023-02-12
D   2023-02-14
D   2023-02-17
D   2023-02-20
E   2023-02-18
```

I want to derive 2 new columns from the dataframe. 1st column **day_difference** tells day diff between that row and previous row at id level. 2nd column **Flag** which tells the pattern at id level. Example id **A** has daily data then mention **Daily**, id **B** has 7 days diff pattern mention **7_days_diff**. id **C** has not any pattern so mention  **No_pattern**. id **E** has only single row, mention **Single_day**.

**Expected output:**

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([["A","2023-02-04","_","1_days_diff"],["A","2023-02-05",1,"1_days_diff"],["A","2023-02-06",1,"1_days_diff"],
                       ["B","2023-02-06","_","7_days_diff"],["B","2023-02-13",7,"7_days_diff"],["B","2023-02-20",7,"7_days_diff"],
                       ["C","2023-02-07","_","No_pattern"],["C","2023-02-10",3,"No_pattern"],["C","2023-02-12",2,"No_pattern"],
                       ["D","2023-02-14","_","3_days_diff"],["D","2023-02-17","3","3_days_diff"],["D","2023-02-20","3","3_days_diff"],
                       ["E","2023-02-18",1,"Single_day"]],columns=["id","date","day_difference","Flag"])
```

```
id     date     day_difference  Flag
A   2023-02-04    _           1_days_diff
A   2023-02-05    1           1_days_diff
A   2023-02-06    1           1_days_diff
B   2023-02-06    _           7_days_diff
B   2023-02-13    7           7_days_diff
B   2023-02-20    7           7_days_diff
C   2023-02-07    _           No_pattern
C   2023-02-10    3           No_pattern
C   2023-02-12    2           No_pattern
D   2023-02-14    _           3_days_diff
D   2023-02-17    3           3_days_diff
D   2023-02-20    3           3_days_diff
E   2023-02-18    1           Single_day
```

How to do it in pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert values to datetimes
df_in['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_in['date'])

#get differencies per groups in days
df_in['day_difference'] = df_in.groupby('id')['date'].diff().dt.days

#get number of unique values and first non missing value
df = df_in.groupby('id')['day_difference'].agg(['nunique','first'])
    
s = df_in['id'].map(df['nunique'])
#create column filled by first non NaNs values
s1 = df_in['id'].map(df['first']).fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str).add('_days_diff')

#set flag column with default value `No_pattern`
df_in['flag'] = np.select([s.eq(1), s.eq(0)], 
                          [s1, 'Single_day'],
                          'No_pattern')
print (df_in)
   id       date  day_difference         flag
0   A 2023-02-04             NaN  1_days_diff
1   A 2023-02-05             1.0  1_days_diff
2   A 2023-02-06             1.0  1_days_diff
3   B 2023-02-06             NaN  7_days_diff
4   B 2023-02-13             7.0  7_days_diff
5   B 2023-02-20             7.0  7_days_diff
6   C 2023-02-07             NaN   No_pattern
7   C 2023-02-10             3.0   No_pattern
8   C 2023-02-12             2.0   No_pattern
9   D 2023-02-14             NaN  3_days_diff
10  D 2023-02-17             3.0  3_days_diff
11  D 2023-02-20             3.0  3_days_diff
12  E 2023-02-18             NaN   Single_day
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a custom function with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
def pattern(g):
    diff = pd.to_datetime(g['date']).diff().dt.days
    return pd.DataFrame({'day_difference': diff,
                         'Flag': 'Single_day' if len(g)==1 else
                         (f'{int(diff.iloc[-1])}_days_diff'
                          if len(diff.dropna().unique())==1
                          else 'No_pattern')
                        })

out = df_in.join(df_in.groupby('id', group_keys=False).apply(pattern))
```

Output:

```
   id        date  day_difference         Flag
0   A  2023-02-04             NaN  1_days_diff
1   A  2023-02-05             1.0  1_days_diff
2   A  2023-02-06             1.0  1_days_diff
3   B  2023-02-06             NaN  7_days_diff
4   B  2023-02-13             7.0  7_days_diff
5   B  2023-02-20             7.0  7_days_diff
6   C  2023-02-07             NaN   No_pattern
7   C  2023-02-10             3.0   No_pattern
8   C  2023-02-12             2.0   No_pattern
9   D  2023-02-14             NaN  3_days_diff
10  D  2023-02-17             3.0  3_days_diff
11  D  2023-02-20             3.0  3_days_diff
12  E  2023-02-18             NaN   Single_day
```